# javax.servlet.LocalStrings - missing resource

Tags: java, android, upnp

All of the sudden, without changes to build environment, gradle files or any source changes that would justify that, my project began crashing with following error:

```
            java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.createServlet(AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.java:96)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.init(AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.java:74)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.startAddressBasedTransports(RouterImpl.java:434)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.enable(RouterImpl.java:132)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidRouter.enable(AndroidRouter.java:92)
            at org.fourthline.cling.UpnpServiceImpl.<init>(UpnpServiceImpl.java:87)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl$1.<init>(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.onCreate(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
            at pl.qus.xenoamp.xenoservice.XenoUpnpService.onCreate(XenoUpnpService.java:104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2785)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1407)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 'javax.servlet.LocalStrings_pl_PL', key ''
            at java.util.ResourceBundle.missingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:238)
            at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:230)
            at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:139)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.<clinit>(GenericServlet.java:95)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.createServlet(AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.java:96)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.init(AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.java:74)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.startAddressBasedTransports(RouterImpl.java:434)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.enable(RouterImpl.java:132)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidRouter.enable(AndroidRouter.java:92)
            at org.fourthline.cling.UpnpServiceImpl.<init>(UpnpServiceImpl.java:87)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl$1.<init>(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.onCreate(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
            at pl.qus.xenoamp.xenoservice.XenoUpnpService.onCreate(XenoUpnpService.java:104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2785)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1407)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Couldn't find much about this on the net, adding dependency for javax serverlet disabled build altogether, complaining about duplicate files from this package.

Currently I had to disable UPnP functionality of my app to get over this error. Please help!

EDIT: interstingly - the error occurs only on apk built in one environment, doesn't occur in another environment.

Comment: Interestingly - it was a build environment problem.

Comment: What was the fix? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: If I could only remember! That was 2 years ago! I'd recommend checking cling dependencies and gradle.

Answer (score -2):

Android does not contains everything from java, for this instance, it has only a limit of javax.*, you simply cannot use it.

Edit:

You can find the list of packages android has here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

Comment: It compiles because android actually use all your java's lib in compile time. It works maybe because you didn't actually access the missing class/files at runtime.

Comment: It is clear that it does NOT exist in android's packages, I dunno why it is necessary to continue to argue on that.

Comment: You're right. It is as unnecessary as stating the obvious.